# Return a text string based on a numeric value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to return a text string based on a numeric value, e.g., if the cell has a value of 1, then it returns on another cell "RED", if it is 2 then "YELLOW", 3 then "GREEN" and so on.

Comment: What version of excel are you running? Also, you forgot to ask a question or give any information on what the problem you are having is.

Answer (score 2):

***Your question is extremely vague, but I will try to answer it for you. In this answer, it is assumed data is in A1 and results are to be in B1.***

Use the `IF` statement to test for the value you desire, then return a value if the test is true or false.

`IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])`

Then using nested `IF` statements you can check for multiple values.

`IF(A1=1, "RED", IF(A1=2, "YELLOW", IF(A1=3,"GREEN")))`

You can then copy the formula down the column as needed.

*NOTE: This should work in all versions of Excel. If this is not working, or you have a vast amount of values to check, please give us more details so we can give you a detailed answer.*

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to create a table of possibilities (I have named this ‘array’ and put it in `F2:G8` - but this could even be on a different sheet) and then if your trigger values are in ColumnA use the formula:

`=LOOKUP(A2,array)`

This could be in `D11` as shown but I have also put it in `B2` and copied that down to `B8` to show how the results vary according to the formula’s first parameter:

[image: SU565704 example]